# React Hook Form how can I call onSubmit in a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm working with React Hook Form. I have a higher order component that is using FormProvider and managing the submitting of the form. I want to trigger this function from a child component. The problem I'm having is that when I call the function in the child component the data in the onSubmit function returns undefined. However it works as expected when I click submit in the same component. What am I doing wrong?

```
const FormGroup = () {
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = data => {
    console.log('data', data);
      dispatch(setEntityInformation({
        data
      }));
    }
  };

  <FormProvider {...methods}>
    <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <section className="sars__sideBar">
        <TabBar
          controls={TAB_CONTROLS.controls}
          activeIndex={index}
          setActiveTab={i => setActiveTab(i)}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
        />
      </section>
      
      <PrimaryButton onClick={() => {
         setActiveTab(index + 1);
      }}
      >
        <input type="submit" value="Continue" /> // submits form as expected
      </PrimaryButton>  
    
    </form>
  </FormProvider>
}
```

// Child component

```
const TabBar = ({ activeIndex, setActiveTab, controls, onSubmit }) => (
  <Tabs>
    {controls.map((control, i) => (
      <div
        className={`tab__wrapper ${i === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}`}
        key={control.key}
        onClick={() => {
          setActiveTab(i);
          if (i > activeIndex) {
            onSubmit(); // function is called, but data is undefined
          }
        }}
      >
        <div className="u-alignCenter">
          <p>{control.label}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="tab__status" />
      </div>
    ))}
  </Tabs>
);
```

Comment: Did you tried using ```useFormContext()``` in the child component?

Comment: useFormContext is meant to be used on deeply nested components. This is just one level down so seems unnecessary.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand the usage of ```FormProvider```.
Maybe calling ```onSubmit``` through ```handleSubmit``` would help? Like this: ```handleSubmit(onSubmit)();```

Comment: @KristofRado Your suggestion worked! The syntax is weird though. Why are there () after the function? Why not methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)?

Comment: I have added this and a little explanation as an answer. If this answers your question, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe calling `onSubmit()` through `handleSubmit` would help? Like this: `handleSubmit(onSubmit)();`

You need this, because handleSubmit is ran asynchronously and with the second parentheses you actually call the returned function.

You can read more about it [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit)